# a bootstrap modal form with on click is not displayed after screen transition or some actions

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript, bootstrap-modal

I want to input with a Bootstrap modal-form everytime in Rails application, but after linking to other pages, or some actions, modal-form is not displayed (then, maybe CoffeScript .on click is not effective). I'm not able to find how to resolve it. I noticed a blue line that run on the web browser directly before when it lose the effectiveness. After refreshing the screen, initializing or some actions again, modal form works well again.

CoffeeScript

```html
$ ->
  $('#topic_new').on 'click', ->
    $('#topic_modal').modal("show")
```

index.html.erb

```html
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<div id="topic_new">
  <%= render "new" %>
</div>
<div id="topic_modal" class="modal fade topic_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <%= render "modal_form" %>
</div>

<h1>Listing Topics</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Index</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @topics.each do |topic| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= topic.index %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', topic, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
```

_new.html.erb

```html
<%= render 'form' %>
```

_form.html.erb

```html
<%= form_for(@topic) do |f| %>
  <% if @topic.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@topic.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this topic from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @topic.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :index %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :index %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

bootstrap_modal_form

```html
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <%= form_for(Topic.new, remote: true, authenticity_token: true) do |f| %>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.text_area :index %>
        </div>
        <%= f.submit 'Create Topic' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

topics_controller.rb

```html
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_topic, only: [:destroy]

  def index
    @topics = Topic.all
    @topic = Topic.new
  end

  def create
    @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @topic.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Topic was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @topic }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @topic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @topic.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to topics_url, notice: 'Topic was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_topic
      @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def topic_params
      params.require(:topic).permit(:index)
    end
end
```

top_controller.rb

```html
class TopController < ApplicationController
  def index
    redirect_to topics_path
  end
end
```

application.html.erb

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>AaaExam</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <%= link_to 'Topic', topics_path %> |
    <%= link_to 'Topic with redirect', root_path %>
  </header>
  <hr>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

coorect screen image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joLKQ.png)

blue line
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA5Ul.png)

Comment: Sorry,  bootstrap_modal_form means the file "_modal_form.html.erb".

Answer (score 0):

In `index.html.erb` file,

```
<div id="topic_modal" class="modal fade topic_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <%= render "modal_form" %>
</div>
```

You try to render `"modal_form"`, but I can't find `_modal_form.html.erb` file. Can you post this file's content.

P/s: Sorry, I dont have enough reputations to write a comment.

Comment: Thanks for reply.